# How would I push down some text in html?

Tags: html, css

I have a background picture in black and white, and I want the text in the to go down and also in the middle of the picture.. However I can't figure out what the issue is, here's my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="fullbackground.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="track_booty/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<h1></h1>
<div style="position:absolute;Down:500px">
<center><h1 style="font-family:'track booty'; font-size:48px;">Go Roam</h1></center>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not use `<center>` anymore, it is an obsolete and deprecated element. Instead, use `text-align: center;` as a CSS style rule on the element for which text should be centered. Also, you should generally put styles into an external CSS file, instead of the inline `style` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You should use 
    top: 
instead of 
    down:

Answer (score 1):

Use this style in your div instead:

```
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Also there is no `Down` property in css.